# assets folder missing in LibGDX project

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, resources, assets

I need to add some files to my `android/assets` folder of my project however, **it isn't there ?** I may have accidentally deleted it without knowing.

**how do I create the `assets folder`?**

Comment: By assets you mean the `res` folder ? Android Studio don't uses an assets folder, maybe if you imported the project from other IDE (like Eclipse) they may have the assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android studio doest provide ASSETS folder by default**

you have to create it from

[image]

---

> ```
>  For the Android plugin, extra files and folders specific to Android:
>
>         AndroidManifest.xml
>         res/
>         assets/
>         aidl/
>         rs/
>         jni/
>         jniLibs/
> ```

Please read [where to place asset folder](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure)